# c# check if a given Sharepoint path is a root sharepoint path?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, path, root

how can i check if a given Sharepoint path through a command line argument is a root sharepoint path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are running command line tool on the server you can use server side SharePoint OM like Petr Abdulin suggested:

new SPSite(url).OpenWeb().IsRootWeb

If you are running code on some random machine (that is not part of the farm) you will have to use Web Services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586(v=office.12).aspx ) or client side OM for SharePoint 2010 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx. Also in this case you sort of have to guess what part of the path is root web - I'd slowly increase prefixes of the Url till I can get SharePoint Web object corresponding to that path.

Comment: Its running on the same machine but i cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can check [SPWeb.IsRootWeb property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.isrootweb%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: this property is not appearing for me.. Im using 2008

Comment: What do you mean by "Im using 2008"? There is not such SharePoint version as I know. Or give an example that you have, and what you want.

Comment: That property is only available in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: +1. 
@kjit: The SPWeb.IsRootWeb property is avaialble since WSS 2.0 I think - definietely in Windows SharePoint Service 2007 and 2010.. It should not really matter what version of Visual Studio you are using.